# How to link Windows license to MS account WITHOUT installing it?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-account, license-key

Just a simple as that, I have a Retail Windows 11 Pro license key appropriate for 2 PCs, and I want to tie it to my MS account (aka digital entitlement), but I have no PC by my hand to install it. How to do this online, **without** installing Windows with this key?

So far I found only this way that is described on different enthusiast sites https://www.makeuseof.com/link-windows-product-key-microsoft-account/ and which somehow corresponds with the [MS official page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows-c39005d4-95ee-b91e-b399-2820fda32227) too

[image]

Is there a way to link the license online without installing? Will the install to temporary VM work?

Comment: It should work in a VM.

Comment: You can install on the same machine in a VM.  A retail license allows you to move the license (not so with OEM) but not use it on 2 physical machines simultaneously.

Comment: You can’t; Only Windows can generate the digital entitlement for the machine, even then, it’s machine specific

Comment: `it’s machine specific` vs `It should work in a VM`??? so I am confused whom to believe. Installing it to VM makes no sense?

Comment: @Suncatcher - It's not complicated, Windows will only generate a digital entitlement, if it's installed on a physical or virtual machine. There is no such thing as a Windows license that can be used on two different machines (virtual or physical). Once you install Windows, and link a local user to your Microsoft Account, the link between the digital entitlement and the Microsoft Account is created.